# How does windows 10 simulator share resources with real computer

Tags: windows, simulator

I have worked with many simulators. They usually are the independent with real computer so I can install any program without affecting my real environment. However, it's very interesting that the simulator of windows 10 shares all resources with the real computer. Inside the simulator, I can open all programs which are installed in real computer, I can access all files of real computer

How does it do that?

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qStpi.png)

Comment: What simulator, where did you get it from? A simulator would be different from an emulator which would be different again from a virtual machine. To me a "simulator" would just be a program that *looks* like the operating system and as such has the same access as any other program on the system. If you want separation then you should install the OS in a VM.

Comment: Are you talking about the dev tool that can be [launched from Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator)? It's rather lacking in documentation and has a horribly unsearchable name :\

Comment: Lacking further information, I would assume that it does *not* provide any separation as a virtual machine or emulator would. Most likely, it merely gives you an independent user session so you can debug a 'full-screen' app without the app clashing with the IDE.

Comment: @Bob That is wrong, Visual Studio uses Hyper-V virtual machines for simulating Windows 8.1 and 10 for both tables and phones. The only difference in the phone case is it's using an Intel variant instead of an ARM variant. Surprisingly, even the Android emulators that come with Visual Studio have a similar architecture, being x86 and using Hyper-V backend.

Comment: @PaulStelian Are you sure? The [simulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator) is very different from the [emulator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-phone-apps-in-the-emulator), the former being for UWP on desktop and the latter being for Windows Phone. Notably, *"The Visual Studio simulator for Windows Store apps does not run in an isolated environment on your local machine."*.

Comment: @PaulStelian In fact, assuming the technology has not changed [since 2011](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator/), this has *absolutely nothing* to do with Hyper-V: *Under the hood the Windows Simulator is a Remote Desktop Session into your local machine.* -- so my guess that it's merely an independent user session seems to be correct.

Comment: @Bob Well what do I know, tablets and phones may in fact be simulated differently. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows tablet "emulation" (simulator) really creates a new Remote Desktop session, running with your account, unlike the mobile emulators which use Hyper-V. I have confirmed this on my local machine, with VS2015.

This means that essentially it's the same computer, and the only thing different is that the RDP client actually can simulate touch events as well as others.